# Right-click the file and do not have the “open with sublime Text 3” option ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sublime-text

In previous sublime text we have the option to open any document with sublime text but after upgrading it. I can't be able to directly open a document with sublime text by right clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a desktop launcher file. You can download a sample of the file from this [github page](https://gist.github.com/thebinarypenguin/2963829).

Create the file named `sublime-text-3.desktop`, paste the content and update the path beside the line Exec (on both location) and Icon. Replace all **Sublime text 2** by **Sublime text 3**. Move the file into /usr/share/applications/.

Make a right click on your text file, click on **Properties**, **Open with** tab and you should able to choose your **Sublime text 3** application.